# Inductive proof for $n\in\Bbb N,\,n\ge4$, is $2^n\ge n^2$ true?

Tags: analysis, inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I need to solve this problem as homework, but neither I nor my classmates have seen through this.

The task is:
Prove the following statement through induction.

given:     $n\in\Bbb N,\,n\ge4$,
to prove:  $2^n\ge n^2$

i've came so far: $2^n*2\ge n^2$ +2n +1

Comment: Always add your attempts with your question.

Comment: I fixed your [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), the most important change being to write `2^{n}` instead of `2n` for $2^n$.

Comment: It is so easy to make first step in induction and make everybody happy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ be the statement $2^n \geq n^2$

$P(4)$ is true since $16 \geq 16$

Now, assume $P(k)$ is true. To prove $P(k+1),

$$
2^{k+1} = 2 * 2^{k} \geq 2 * k^2 \geq k^2 + 4k > k^2 + 2k + 1 = (k+1)^2
$$

since $k \geq 4$. Therefore $P(k)$ is true implies $P(k+1)$ is true.

Conclude the result by induction.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't show work but claim you and others have struggled together, I'll concentrate on clarifying how to structure one of these proofs while leaving the hard part of this proof as an exercise.

We split an inductive proof into proving the base step and the inductive step.

- For us, the former is $n=4$, so $2^n=n^2=16$.
- For the inductive step, we want to prove for $k\ge4$ that if $\color{red}{2^k\ge k^2}$ then $\color{blue}{2^{k+1}\ge(k+1)^2}$. But by the inductive hypothesis (the red part), $2^{k+1}=2\cdot2^k\ge2k^2$, and to prove this implies the blue part we just need to show $2k^2\ge(k+1)^2$. I'll leave that part to you.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my MathJax